# Alfresco - create online survey with forms

Tags: forms, alfresco, alfresco-share, survey

I am searching for a way (or a case study) where Alfresco is used to perform a survey by providing a form. The Alfresco Share visitors/users fill-in the fields of this form and by submission the results are transfered to a data list, filling in the respective fields. (something similar to google forms).

Does anyone know of such a case? How can something like this be materialized? Can Alfresco forms be used this way, or do I have it totally wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This really isn't a good use for Alfresco.

Alfresco is an Enterprise Content Management system that stores your content as documents, files, etc along with associated metadata and there is nothing I can see in the use case you have provided that has to do with storing documents and/or metadata.

No matter what way I look at this it is going to be difficult to create a configurable survey. Your best bet is to look to having another survey tool such as [Encuestame](http://www.encuestame.org/) that you can deploy to your same Tomcat container and database and then share links to your surveys in Alfresco and publish results/reports to documents in Alfresco.

Answer (score 1):

You have custom dashlet for creating pools on [Share Extras](http://share-extras.github.io/addons/site-poll-dashlet/). 
I didn't tried it yet, but I don't think you'll have problems with deploying/using it.

Answer (score 0):

It not a good way of using alfresco Instead of that you will find below way usefull.

There is one web application called orbeon forms.Which is helpfull in creating web form. Orbeon provides community version by which you can test.below is the link of site for orbeon form.

http://www.orbeon.com/

1. Create webform in orbeon.There are 2 interface in orbeon one is form builder using which you can create web form another is form runner using which you can enter data.

   Orbeon provides support for submitting data which you can change to alfresco.Here you need to put rest url of alfresco webscript

   Create rest api in alfresco for saving orbeon forms.

Hope this helps!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The question was also asked in the French section of Alfresco forum in 2013. While there are "Alfresco Forms", these have a completely different meaning, nothing in common with Google Forms. As an Alfresco add-on, "Form Factor" is an answer if you have entreprise and 5.5KUSD/CPU to pay each year.